# Assign new values to certain tensor elements in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I need to change the value of some elements of a tensor. I know what elements -- they are in a boolean tensor already.

I don't see how to do this in keras code. But if I were **using TensorFlow code** I would do something like this:

[Conditional assignment of tensor values in TensorFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39045797/conditional-assignment-of-tensor-values-in-tensorflow)

In **python numpy**, the code would look something like this:

```
x = np.zeros_like(sometensor) 
x[sometensor>0.5] = 1.0
```

In Keras code (and I'm using TF backend) here's my best attempt (does not work):

```
encoder_outputs_bin = k.backend.zeros_like(encoder_outputs, name="encoder_outputs_bin")
point_five = k.backend.constant(0.5, shape=k.backend.shape(encoder_outputs), name="point_five")
positives = k.backend.greater_equal(encoder_outputs, point_five)
encoder_outputs_bin[positives].assign(tf.ones(1)) # TF syntax -- might not work in keras
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48795910/binarize-tensor-in-keras

Comment: Following code seems nice but Keras throws error at train time: encoder_outputs = Dense(units=latent_vector_len, activation='sigmoid', kernel_initializer="lecun_normal")(x)
encoder_outputs_bin = k.layers.Lambda(lambda z: k.backend.round(z))(encoder_outputs)

Comment: Is there a trivially easy solution using categorical cross entropy loss, which somehow performs the binarization internally and computes loss on that 2-value categorical variable?

Comment: Round() is not differentiable, causing errors in Keras when Keras tries to compute gradient it seems.  However Relu is not differentiable but it works fine as everyone knows, so maybe there is similarly a way to get Round to make Keras happy.

Comment: Relu is differentiable. Only when it's in the zero region it gets a zero gradient. (But the movement of the other vars which are in the differentiable zone may rescue the others from the zero or not). --- Relu is ok as long as you don't have the unfortunate case of all elements going to 0, then your model gets stuck).

Comment: As an easy solution for many possible classes, you can use `binary_crossentropy`. (Compared to `categorical_crossentropy`, binary can take many true classes, while categorical takes only one).

Answer (score 0):

This answer is not really "assign", it's getting another tensor, but I believe it will do...

Also, what you intend to do will totally break backpropagation for these elements.

Knowing this:

```
positives = k.backend.greater_equal(encoder_outputs, 0.5)
positives = k.backend.cast(positives, k.backend.floatx())

encoder_outputs = positives + ((1-positives)*encoder_outputs)
```

Comment: Need backprop though.

Comment: Then don't make them constant.

Comment: I will give a vairalbe a try if I get time. Thanks for playing.

Answer (score 0):

A lambda function in the activation worked for me. It is one step more complicated than the simple use of a built-in activation function.

```
encoder_outputs = Dense(units=latent_vector_len, activation=k.layers.Lambda(lambda z: k.backend.round(k.layers.activations.sigmoid(x=z))), kernel_initializer="lecun_normal")(x)
```

This code changes the output of a Dense from Reals to 0,1 (ie, binary).

Keras throws a warning but the code still proves to work.

```
# Look it works!

y = encoder_model.predict(x=x_in)
print(y)

>>>[[1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0.]]
```

Comment: Round is one of the functions that will not backpropagate, though. :(
When fitting, you will see either "An operation has None for gradient" or "None values not supported".